# Is it possible to prevent userclick on a deactivated window but allow tooltips?

Tags: wpf

I have two windows open at a time, Suppose I click one button on a deactivated(non focused) window, I dont want the code behind the button to work, unless the user click the button again. At the same time, I want to show the tooltip when the user place the cursor on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put `IsHitTestVisible = false` in the grid of the window where I want the above behaviour and I get the expected behaviour

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use following property to show tool tips on disabled state

```
ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"
```